# How to enable revision in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Automatically disable transcripts in WordPress,
What should be done to **enable** copy in WordPress in a mandatory way or through a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `WP_POST_REVISIONS` options ?

https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/